# Adding new roles to WSO2 API-M with login & subscribe permissions does not allow user to login to subscriber portal

Tags: wso2-api-manager, roles, wso2, scopes

I'm using WSO2 API-M v3.0.0, and I have created a new role with Login & Subscribe permissions (same permissions that are granted to the "Internal/subscriber" role). But users within this new role are unable to login to the subscriber portal as access is being denied to them. The only workaround I see is to add those users to both the new role AND the Internal/subscriber role.

Are there any other changes that need to be done when any new role is created? I am **not** using a multi-tenant environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From APIM 3.0 onwards, the permission-based access control model is replaced with a role-based + permission-based model. So, by default, your users need to have the `Internal/subscriber` role to access the developer portal.

This is how it works. To access the developer portal, users should be able to get access tokens which have `apim:api_subscribe` scope. For that users need to have the `Internal/subscriber` role. This mapping is configured in `/_system/config/apimgt/applicationdata/tenant-conf.json` file in the registry. So, in your case you have to add your new role to this file.

From APIM 3.1 onwards, there will be a UI to configure this, which will make it easier than what we have now.

From docs[1].

> In WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0, Developer Portal and Publisher Web
>   Application UIs are populated by API-M REST APIs and all the
>   authentication and authorization to access the different components in
>   the UI solely depend on the scope role mapping defined in
>   /_system/config/apimgt/applicationdata/tenant-conf.json that can be
>   accessed through the Management Console from Resources > Browse.
>
> By default, the scope-role mapping contains Internal/creator,
>   Internal/publisher, Internal/subscriber as the default roles. If there
>   are custom roles defined with API creator, API publisher, admin and
>   API subscriber permissions, those roles have to be configured in
>   tenant-conf.json under relevant scopes.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Administer/ProductAdministration/ManagingUsersAndRoles/managing-user-roles/

Comment: Worked like a charm, ty! I missed this information in the documentation and thanks for posting that link and a snippet from that post, got me my answer in seconds!